Find an efficient algorithm to find for every vertex  ∈ , a path from  to  with maximum weight.
The question :
Let graph  = (, ) be a directed acyclic graph. Let  ∈  and let $$ :  → ℝ^+ $$be a nonnegative weight function. Describe an efficient algorithm to find for every vertex  ∈ , a path from  to  with maximum weight.
My answer: I know that we can contract a new graph, with inverse weight function and run DAG shortest-paths Algorithm (which using TopoSort) which costs: O(|V| +|E|). But it looks not that necessary because if we want to return the shortest path (not the distance) for every  ∈  we should run path(v) function (recrusion of v.π) which can costs us in total of $$ O(|V|^2) $$ which cancels the effectiveness of the DAG shortest-paths Algorithm, what I'm missing here?

It looks to me a variant of longest path problem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem).

Of course but the main issue of the question was about the complexity of returning the path for all the vertices which even in shortest paths problem can cause O(|V|^2)
